# What is the diameter $D$ of a square portion of square lattice, with $L$ nodes along each side, for a network of network size $N$?

Tags: graph-theory, network

> What is the diameter $D$ of a square portion of square lattice, with
> $L$ nodes along each side, for a network of network size $N$?

My understanding is that each edge has $L$ nodes, and the square of $L$ is equal to $N, D=2(L-1)$. But the next question is to ask: "show that the leading term of $D$ in terms of the total number of nodes $N$ in the network, in the limit $N >> 1$ ，D ≈ radical N.

So I want to know how to understand this problem. (The example graph gives a 6×6 node graph.)